# Fill the available space in Listtile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am new to the flutter and trying to fill the empty space in the listtile. I tried to use dense and visualDensity but with that, I am not getting the required result. Any support and suggestions will be appreciated.

here is my code and output:

```
Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: isLargeScreen ? 300 : 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
                 physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 itemCount: tags.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                 return CheckboxListTile(
                      value: tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id),
                      onChanged: (e) {
                      setState(() {
                            if (tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id)) {
                              tempSelectedTags.remove(tags[index].id);
                            } else {
                              tempSelectedTags.add(tags[index].id);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        title: Text(
                          tags[index].name,
                          style: !tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id)
                              ? theme.textTheme.labelMedium?.copyWith(
                                  color: ThemeConfig.colorTertiary)
                              : theme.textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(
                                  color: ThemeConfig.colorTertiary),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:sdPaddingMedium),
                child: SdPrimaryButton(
                  title: appLocalizations.btnApply,
                  onPressed: () {
                    viewModel.setTags(tempSelectedTags);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

[Output can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmPnH.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome, what exactly do you mean with "filling the available space"? What should it look like in the end and what does it look like now?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two important things that determine the vertical layout in your column.

1. The whole box has a fixed size

> ```
> SizedBox(
>     height: isLargeScreen ? 300 : 200,
> ```

2. There is a flexible space between the checkbox options and the bottom-right button

> ```
> const Spacer(),
> ```

So if you want to remove the space, you can either

- reduce the overall box size or
- replace the `const Spacer` with a constant spacing like
  `SizedBox(height: 50)` and also remove the SizedBox, so that the whole box will be content-sized

Comment: thanks, @JoRa for your suggestion. if i am doing what you have suggested them I am getting an overflow if i run it on iPhone and if i run it on macOS there is an empty space below the apply button i can share the image but i don't know how to post it inside the comment

Comment: i fixed it by changing the Sizebox with Flexible and removing the height: isLargeScreen ? 300 : 200, and also the spacer() widget. It's working fine and that is the result I was looking for. Thanks for your suggestions and response!